# Is there a way to download additional stemming packages for Recoll?

Tags: recoll

Recoll's list of languages where stemming is available via Xapian algorithm lacks a language in which most of my documents are written.

I searched both in the Recoll manual for ways of downloading more languages as well as on Xapian website, but there seems to be no additional languages.

So, are these languages the only ones supported for stemming?

- arabic
- armenian
- basque
- catalan
- danish
- dutch
- english
- finnish
- french
- german
- hungarian
- italian
- norwegian
- portuguese
- romanian
- spanish
- russian
- swedish
- turkish

Comment: You can look at https://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/ which has "If you run into a problem, or want to propose improvements, you are welcome to use the [mailing list or problem tracker](https://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/support.html)." IIRC, the developer is quite accessible and responsive.

Comment: Somehow late, Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, and what's your language ?

Answer (score 1):

Recoll uses Xapian which has Snowball sub-project. Here are current available [stemming algorithms](https://github.com/snowballstem/snowball/tree/master/algorithms)

```
arabic.sbl
basque.sbl
catalan.sbl
danish.sbl
dutch.sbl
english.sbl
finnish.sbl
french.sbl
german.sbl 
german2.sbl
greek.sbl   
hindi.sbl   
hungarian.sbl 
indonesian.sbl  
irish.sbl   
italian.sbl     
kraaij_pohlmann.sbl     
lithuanian.sbl  
lovins.sbl  
nepali.sbl  
norwegian.sbl   
porter.sbl
portuguese.sbl 
romanian.sbl    
russian.sbl     
serbian.sbl     
spanish.sbl     
swedish.sbl     
tamil.sbl   
turkish.sbl
```

Comment: Can you explain how to augment `recoll` with those snowball files?